# How to access Default Settings from user control?

Tags: c#, user-controls, settings

How to access Default Settings  from user control?

when I use this code

```
namespace SearchControl{
public partial class SearchControl : UserControl   
{
     string ConncStr = Properties.Settings["myConnectionString"].toString();
}}
```

not worked

```
Properties.Settings["myConnectionString"].toString()
```

I want to access Properties.Settings["myConnectionString"]
in usercontrol from project which usercontrol added on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var secGroup = config.SectionGroups["userSettings"]; // or applicationSettings

if (secGroup != null)
{
    var clientSettings = (ClientSettingsSection)secGroup.Sections[0];

    var settingElementCollection = clientSettings.Settings;

    var setting = settingElementCollection.Get(Name);

    var value = setting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string conStr = Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Most statements end with `;` not `}`.

```
namespace SearchControl;

public partial class SearchControl : UserControl   
{
 string ConncStr = Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString;
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397759(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You did not understand me.